# Как узнать позицию активного объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В объекте `CharacterList` есть несколько объектов, один из которых будет активен, мне нужно узнать его позицию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
//массив наших объектов, задаем в инспекторе 
public GameObject[] characterList;
//локально храним нашу позицию
private Vector3 position;

for(int i = 0; i < characterList.Length;i++){
   //В цикле проверяем активен ли наш объект в сцене
   // GameObject.activeSelf - проверка на активность без проверки активности родителей объекта
   if(characterList[i]..activeInHierarchy())
        position = characterList[i].transform.position;

}
```

upd: Все есть в оф.документации https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html